# How to write a query in Google Spreadsheet that returns date >= today?

Tags: google-sheets

I am writing the following =filter formula in Google spreadsheet:
=FILTER('Tab'!6:1963, ‘Tab’!E6:E1963 = "Major", ’Tab’!D6:D1963 > NOW())

Column D are dates and I am interested in including today.  For instance today is the 7/19 and I would like to have the data that includes 7/19.  My current formula returns values only from tomorrow (7/20).  I tried the **now()-1** but returned an #VALUE!.

Any help?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782256/how-to-compare-dates-with-query-on-google-sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOW()` returns a datetime object (which includes the time). If you are comparing with a date, `NOW()` will (almost :) ) always be greater than the date alone (which would have a time component of 12:00 A.M., which is essentially `0`).

Try using `TODAY()` to get the date only (adding/subtracting `1` will use tomorrow/yesterday, respectively).