# Query Col1 > today()

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

When I use the format that I left below, returns in error, I know that something is missing adjusting in relation to `WHERE` `AND`... But I could not fit to supply the error.

I would like some help knowing what I missed.

```
"select Col1,Col2,Col3 where Col1 is not null Order by Col1, Col2 AND Col1 > date'"&TEXT(today()-1,"yyyy/mm/dd")&"'"
```

The date and time for `Col1` and `Col2` are like this:

[image]

With this formula, I hope I can filter the imported data only for those that have the date of the current day or tomorrow and that today's games are higher than the current time.

Link to spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15T4UPVtEHv43DLomKcTmdaPuGWMsBUoO7bLvlOhab4k/edit?usp=sharing

> Formula set in Página1 G2

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding private or confidential information), and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: @Tedinoz done mate!

Comment: Would you please edit your question to explain what outcome your are trying to achieve with this formula?

Comment: @Tedinoz I edited, put what I want well above the spreadsheet link. Sorry for the flaws in my question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782256/how-to-compare-dates-with-query-on-google-sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may look like you can combine parameters as you like but there is a specific order that needs to be followed:

[image: 0]

respectively joining operator like `and` needs to be proceeded by parent parameter `where`:

[image]

Comment: There are times when only one upvote isn't enough. This is one of those times.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`"select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 >='"&TEXT(TODAY()-1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col1 is not null Order by Col1, Col2"`

This returns 78 records