# Query and Today Function

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

This formula should filter all results between today and 7 days from now from another sheet but it gives a *Formula parse error*:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A3:H13;"SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H WHERE (A >= date '"&text(TODAY(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' AND A <= date '"&text(TODAY()+7,"yyyy-MM-dd")& "')"; false)
```

If I use this formula instead:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A3:H13;"SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H WHERE (A >= date '2020-11-08' AND A <= date '2020-11-15')"; false)
```

It works but it would need to change dates manually everytime.
Where I am wrong?

Comment: after TODAY() you need to use ; not ,

Comment: Can't believe the problem was a single ;

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782256/how-to-compare-dates-with-query-on-google-sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A3:H13;
 "where A >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY();   "yyyy-MM-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+7; "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'"; 0)
```