# GOOGLE SHEET FORMULA - QUERY STUFF FOR TODAYS DATE ONLY

Tags: google-sheets

new poster here :-) this place as helped me throughout my years of learning I.T stuff as I progress through Adulthood

So this formula im having an issue with with is for a Google SHeet.

basically I want a SHEET that only displays todays ATTENDANCE, and not YESTERDAY or previous dates attendance.  So I have two sheets (Today) and (NewData)

New Data (Sheet)
[Picture Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KglVi.png)

TODAY Attendance Sheet
[Picture 2 Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zocFO.png)

now my formula is this as follows, the part that is broken is the ending (everything after =, as the = should reference cell B1 of Today Attendance Sheet, so it auto populates any new inputted data throughout the day

=QUERY(NewData!$A$1:$H$136,"select A, C, B where E = date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/1/2000"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)

BROKEN WRONG CODE  is “”””= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE("1/1/2000"),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)“”””

Comment: Is date a named range on your sheet. It might be better to offer links to copies of your actual spreadsheet, with names removed or replaced.

Comment: If my answer is sufficient please select it as being correct

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45782256/how-to-compare-dates-with-query-on-google-sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like `FILTER` better than `QUERY`

```
=FILTER({'New Data'!A2:A,'New Data'!C2:C,'New Data'!B2:B}, DATEVALUE(LEFT('New Data'!A2:A,FIND(" ",'New Data'!A2:A))) = $B$1)
```

### Todays Attendance Sheet

[image]

### New Data Sheet

[image]

Comment: thank you!! and yes that filter function is much more practical and what I needed to get this done :) thanks.